# Does Windows "N" plus Feature Pack exactly equal Windows non-N?

Tags: windows

The "N" versions of Windows have had the media features deleted, both the underlying OS support libraries as well as the user-level apps such as Media Player, Groove, Skype, etc. Does adding the Feature Pack to a Windows N installation make it the exact equivalent to the non-N version, or are there still differences that need to be accounted for?

Background: I manage a software testing lab. I have a bunch of Windows 8 "N" licenses that are unused. With the free Windows 10 upgrade window about to close, I wish to determine whether or not it is worthwhile to install, activate and upgrade those licenses. My definition of "worthwhile" is that installing the "Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N and Windows 10 KN editions (November 2015)" on top of Windows 10 N will result in a full, uncrippled version of Windows 10.

Comment: As far as I can tell from [KB3099229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229) and various internet websites, it restores all of the missing functionality, including the non-obvious stuff like talking to an Android device over USB. Because removing this functionality was mandated by certain countries, the Microsoft verbiage is intentionally vague.

Comment: I must have read KB3099299 a dozen times today, and as you say, it is maddeningly vague on what actually happens when you install the Feature Pack. And assuming that it does restore everything back to "normal," will that restoration survive a system refresh, or installing a new build such as the impending 1607? Who know?!?

Comment: It occurs to me that the people who might have actual experience with this probably don't speak or read English.

Comment: 1607 is on the insider preview fast ring right now, so you could try it out for yourself...